# Opencv c# выделение контуров

Tags: c#, opencv

Подскажите, как выделить контур в изображении? Поток я получаю из вебкамеры, а что дальше - не понимаю.

Я пробовал `Cv.FindContours` но у меня возникает ошибка, что эта функция работает только с `8uc1` images.

Вот код:

```
int counter = 0;
IplImage frame = null;
IplImage src = null;
CvCapture capture = null;
CvMemStorage storage = new CvMemStorage();
CvSeq<CvPoint> contours = null;
public void video(ref PictureBox pictureBox1, ref Label label1)
{
    try
    {
        capture = new CvCapture(0);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("[!] Error: cant open camera.");
    }

    if (capture != null)
    {
        double width = capture.GetCaptureProperty(CaptureProperty.FrameWidth);
        double height = capture.GetCaptureProperty(CaptureProperty.FrameHeight);

        while (true)
        {
            capture.GrabFrame();
            frame = capture.RetrieveFrame();

            // windowCapture.ShowImage(frame);
            // frame.FindContours(storage,out  contours);
            Cv.FindContours(frame, storage, out contours);
            pictureBox1.Image = frame.ToBitmap();

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Перед вызовом floodfill необходимо произвести бинаризацию изображения (допустим из RGB формата, оставить на изображении только чёрное и белое), а бинаризацию производить можно разными способами. Например, пороговое преобразование по цвету, попробуйте сделать например так:

`Cv2.CvtColor(исходное, полученное, метод преобразования ColorConversion.RgbToGray);` - переводим изображение в градации серого

`Cv2.Threshold(исходное, полученное, пороговое значение например 50, 255, ThresholdType.Otsu);` - оставляем только черное и белое

После этого `findContours` найдет места на изображении, где черное переходит в белое.